# How can I change the color of string values I type?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, customization, command-prompt, powershell-5.0

In my job I have recently begun using Powershell quite frequently.  To facilitate using it, I am attempting to customize the command prompt colors to my liking, but I have run into a snag when attempting to customize the color of quoted string values.  Given how PS is a text based interface, this statement may not mean that much, so please refer to this

[image: Picture with the offending(ly?) colored text surrounded with a yellow box]

Apparently I can't embed images yet, so you'll have to click the link.
Anyway, this text is extremely difficult for me to read, and I am attempting to switch it over to something with more contrast, but I can't find a setting for it.

I've looked at the following options already:

1. Setting these colors in the UI (right-click context menu), but that only allows setting default foreground and background
2. Setting the color utilizing `$host.UI.RawUI`, but this also only allows setting the default foreground and background
3. Setting the color using $host.PrivateData, but while this provides more options, it doesn't seem to have options for setting the more context sensitive items like the quoted text or even the variable you can see in the image.

My fallback plan is to use PowerShell ISE if I must (it allows me to customize this), but I would prefer to have a lighter weight command prompt available if possible.

Has anyone figured out how to change this?

I'm using PowerShell v5 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PowerShell 5.0 ships with [PSReadLine](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt560330.aspx), a module that enhances the editing experience in the console by adding syntax highlight coloring among other things.

You can change the color of string tokens with `Set-PSReadLineOption`, for example:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

[image]

---

For PSReadLine version 2.0 and up, use the `-Colors` parameter and supply a dictionary of (optional) token color overrides to [`Set-PSReadLineOption`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/7984b6ecc01193f9769aab006fc8ec56aa565e30/docs/Set-PSReadLineOption.md):

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ String = 'Cyan' }
```

Comment: Just tested this...exactly what I needed.  Thanks a million!

Comment: @jfc Happy to help! If it solved your problem, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark symbol on the left

Comment: One other bit of info for anyone else new to PowerShell: to persist these changes you'll need to add the commands to your PowerShell profile. You can see a reasonably good description of how to use the profiles here: [Customizing PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)

Comment: This setting does not persist, it must be entered again if you start a new PS console window. :(

Comment: @Paul that is easily fixed by putting the code in your [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)

Comment: Syntax was changed in Win10 v1809: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/738, https://blog.ppedv.de/post/PowerShell-PSReadlineOption-not-working